# Bufferedreader stops reading

Tags: java, curl, server, inputstream, bufferedreader

After reading the whole string, the reader stay stuck in while, and even don't throw exception. I'm sending a request via curl to server.

I have tried to change the Content-Type of the curl, change the content of the string, and use another way to read the input, like scanner, but alway get stucked on while.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "asdasdasdashdiasdasgdasgduascuyasvccccc" 192.168.0.59:8080
```

```java
    // Read characters from the client via input stream on the socket
    in = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
    // Get character output stream to client (for headers)
    out = new PrintWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
    // Get binary output stream to client (for requested data)
    dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());

    // Get first line of the request from the client
    input = in.readLine();
    // Parse the request with a string tokenizer
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input");
        return;
    }

    parse = new StringTokenizer(input);

    method = parse.nextToken().toUpperCase();
    input = in.readLine();

    do {

        parse = new StringTokenizer(input);
        if (parse.hasMoreTokens()) {
            header = parse.nextToken().toUpperCase(); // we get the 
        HTTP method of the client
        }
        if (parse.hasMoreTokens()) {
            hValue = parse.nextToken().toLowerCase();
        }

        // Support only GET and HEAD methods, we check
        out.println(header + hValue);
        System.out.println(header + hValue);
        if (header.equals("CONTENT-TYPE:")) {
            readFile(in);
        }
        input = in.readLine();
    } while (!input.isEmpty());

    private void readFile(BufferedReader file) throws IOException {
        try {
            int count;
            count = 0;

            while ((count = file.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) count);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            file.close();
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
Server started.

Listening for connections on port : 8080 ...

Connection opened. (Mon Aug 26 15:44:49 BRT 2019)

HOST:192.168.0.59:8080

USER-AGENT:curl/7.58.0

ACCEPT:*/*

CONTENT-TYPE:text/plain

Content-Length: 39

asdasdasdashdiasdasgdasgduascuyasvccccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your client (curl) isn't closing the connection, hence

```
(count = file.read()) != -1
```

Keeps returning true as the count is set to 0 over and over after the last character is read.

You need to ensure that either the client closes the connection, or to send message length along with message, and close it serverside (in java) when the sent number of characters has been received.

The later could be done like so:

1) send

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "5asdas" 192.168.0.59:8080
```

2) update code to first read the length, and then count down until 0 and close connection like so

```
private void readFile(BufferedReader file) throws IOException {
    int expectedCount = -1;
    try {
            int count;
            count = 0;

            while ((count = file.read()) != -1 && (expectedCount > 0 || expectedCount == -1 ) ) {
                if ( expectedCount == -1 ) {
                    // read count and set in expectedCount
                } else {
                    //do what you need to do with the input
                    System.out.print((char) count);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            file.close();
        }
    }
```

Please note that this solution doesn't account for a ton of stuff like multi-digit lengths, but should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Like you said, i get the content length and use one variable auxiliar to count if the actual index is greater than zero, and worked, but i think that it is one way to get around the error, and not fix it.

Comment: Now i understand what you were trying to say to me kkk, i was reading the header and the content sent from the client on the same while, to fix it, i just read the header first and them on another while, and then, use the readFile method as you showed using same BufferedReader using actual content length provided in the header section. Briefly, first we need to read the header and after it, read the content sent from the client.

Answer (score 0):

you need deal with `close` of `BufferedReader` and related I/O classes property if are using pre-Java8.

Comment: After the catch tag i call close method in the code, "finally { file.close(); }", if is what you is talking about, still get stuck on while after read all string

Comment: seems someone point out the root cause `your client (curl) isn't closing the connection` already.